# How I can use that code with two dropdown menus?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How I can use that code with two dropdown menus? Actually when I reload the page the first dropdown menu stays like I want but the second one no. Thanks. Sorry to ask, Im new in all this incredible world!

var init = function () {
strong text
var sel = $("select"),
but = $("button");

```
    var clearSelected = function () {
      sel.find(":selected").prop("selected", false);
    };
  
    if (localStorage.getItem("pref")) {
      var pref = localStorage.getItem("pref");
      clearSelected();
      //set the selected state to true on the option localStorage remembers
      sel.find("#" + pref).prop("selected", true);
    }
  
    var setPreference = function () {
      //remember the ID of the option the user selected
      localStorage.setItem("pref", sel.find(":selected").attr("id"));
    };
  
    var reset = function () {
      clearSelected();
      localStorage.setItem("pref", undefined);
    };
  
    sel.on("change", setPreference);
    but.on("click", reset);
  };
  $(init);
  **strong text**
```

Comment: Add a minimal replicate code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `.filter` is what your need here. See [this](https://api.jquery.com/filter/)
`.find` will return the first element it founds that responds to the criteria you give. That's why your first dropdowm list is correct and not the second.
Also, for your storage, I guess you have 2 choices:

- Set an item for the first dropdown menu, and another one for the second one that you can handle separatly.
- Set only one item but containing an array of the values selected. With this solution you would have to set the item with an object as [so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2010948/11398936)

Hope I helped.

**EDIT**

I think [this](https://codesandbox.io/embed/jquery-playground-forked-fro3f?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) should do the math

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer but I still do not get it. Can you give me an example, please? Sorry to bother you. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Since I'm bad with my explanations, I've made you a codesandbox with comments. Check edits on my answer

Comment: You don't know how I appreciate that. Thank you so much! I was fighting against it all day! Seriously, thank you so much.